# Fade in multiple div (including images) one by one using waypoints

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

Basically, what I am trying to do here is to fade in 3 div one by one when the user scroll to the bottom of the page.

I searched online and found that this could be accomplished by using a jquery plugin called waypoints. However, I am completely new at Jquery and I really can't figure out how to do this.

If anyone can kindly look at my codes and tell me what did I do wrong, it will be really helpful!

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!--#Div1-->
    <div class="span4" id="fadein1" style="display:none">
    <img src="images/41.jpg" alt="41%" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="41">
        <h2>Boba</h2> 
        <p>We strive for <b>perfection</b> when we prepare our boba 
to use. Not under, nor overcooked to mush. Just right and still chewy.</p>

    </div><!-- /.span4 -->
        <div class="span4" id="fadein2" style= "display:none;">
        <img src="images/43.jpg" alt="43%" style="" id="43">
          <h2>Tea Leaves</h2>
          <p>Tea Powders? <b>NEVER!</b> Premixes? <b>Absolutely not!</b> 
We use only the best quality house blend tea leaves.</p>

    </div><!-- /.span4 -->    

    <div class="span4" id="fadein3" style="display:none;">
          <img src="images/44.jpg" alt="44%" style="" id="44">
          <h2>Customized Blend</h2>
          <p>It is our goal to customize your drink the way 
<b>you</b> want it to be. 75% sugar? Light ice? You name 
it, and we will make it happen!</p>

    </div><!-- /.span4 -->
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // call waypoint plugin
    $("#fadin1").waypoint( function( bottom-in-view ) {
        $(this).fadein(1500);
   }, {
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
   }

   $("#fadin2").waypoint( function( bottom-in-view ) {
        $(this).fadein(2000);
   }, {
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
   }

   $("#fadin3").waypoint( function( bottom-in-view ) {
        $(this).fadein(2500);
   }, {
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. Your divs will fadein when scroll reach their divs.

I think you should have some content top and bottom of these hidden divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fadein1').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn(1500);
}, {
    offset: function() {
       return -$(this).height();
    }
});

$('#fadein2').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
}, {
    offset: function() {
       return -$(this).height();
    }
});

$('#fadein3').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn(2500);
}, {
    offset: function() {
       return -$(this).height();
    }
});
});
```

HTML should be like...

```
<div>Top content 1</div>
<div>Top content 1</div>

<div>Your hidden div 1</div>
<div>Your hidden div 2</div>
<div>Your hidden div 3</div>

<div>Below content 1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly just as I wanted it to be. One question tho, isn't the "direction" and "event" an argument that I have to input? In this example, shouldn't I input "down" in the direction section? How does it work?

Comment: glad it works. :)
you can use without these argument, or use them if you want to add direction or handler event.
for detail, check here... http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started

Comment: The `event` parameter is no longer used in Waypoints 2.x. It's an old 1.x thing. The waypoint callback only receives the `direction` parameter now. I know this answer does not use those parameters, just letting you know. :)